# Oauth in node.js with soundcloud

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, soundcloud

I am trying to get music information from soundcloud using node.js, however I can't figure how to get the Oauth value to use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-soundcloud npm package to access this music data. I appreciate any ideas on how I can retrieve the Oauth code for soundcloud in advance.

Comment: Please post your code or be more specific

Comment: @kyrylkov As of now, I have no code. My goal is to be able to search for a song (ex: Gangam Style) and then once searched for, take the songID of the first option there is. Any ideas on how I can do that?

Comment: Here is the search API docs: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#search